# How to model a real-world graphical structure into a mathematical formulation?

Tags: proof-writing, mathematical-modeling, learning

I am trying to learn how to model programming problems in a mathematical way. I am a software engineer, but have recently been running into road blocks where I can't solve some problems very efficiently because I can't reason about it using mathematical thinking. So this question is coming from that perspective: I want to learn how to formulate programming problems mathematically, so I can start manipulating them using set theory and stuff like that.

One problem I run into a lot is in modeling data. Here is currently the way I describe it to myself:

- You have a single database *schema*.
- There are a set of *models* in that schema (or database tables).
- Each model/table has a set of *attributes* (or for a table, columns).
- Some attributes might be *relations*. That is, a model has "simple" attributes and "relational" attributes. The relations just point to other models.

So a specific example might be a blog:

- A blog schema might have 3 models: user, article, comment
- The user model might have these attributes: firstName, lastName, email
- The article model might have attributes: title, body, userId
- The comment model might have attributes: message, articleId

The "simple" attributes are ones like email/firstName/title/etc. The "relational" attributes are ones that point to other models, like `userId` in the article model, or `articleId` in the comment model.

In trying to wrap my head around what's actually happening, I try to think about this in terms of sets, because in the end, the models/attributes in a schema form a graph. But I don't know how to formulate these sets properly into equations. Without being able to think like that, I am unable to easily reason about things like graph traversals and shortest paths and such. I don't know how to model the above description/list into a mathematical formulation. Which is the reason for asking. How would you model this in a mathematical way?

Here is what I've tried so far:

The set of all attributes on a model is defined as $a(m)$. The set of all models in a schema is defined as $M(s)$, where $s$ is a single schema. So then you could say, $m∈M(s)$. (Is this how you would would formulate it as well, or what am I doing wrong?)

Then you can say, the set of all attributes in a schema $s$ is defined as $a(s) = \bigcup_{m\in M(s)} a(m)$. Is that how you would write that, or is there a different way? Maybe instead of $a(s)$ you would do $a_s$? I don't know.

Then you could say, the set of relations on a model is a subset of the attributes on a model: $r(m) ⊆ a(m)$. And so, the set of all relations in a schema is $r(s) = \bigcup_{m\in M(s)} r(m)$.

Is this correct? Or what is the correct/preferred way to formulate this? I am not looking for a proof or anything, but just how you would formulate this using mathematical symbols. Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you're overthinking things. What insights are you really going to gain from expressing a problem using a particular set of symbols convened on by a particular group of early 20th century intellectuals?

Comment: I understand. My goal is to just try to find _some_ problem that will help me understand how to take "ideas" and convert them to "mathematical symbols". I don't learn well by doing practice problems from a book that have no relevance to my life, so I am coming up with sample problems for myself to keep me interested. Up to this point I still don't understand how you take some idea, and abstract it into an equation. Input = thoughts, output = equation. How? :)

Comment: Like, I imagine when coming up with the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Definition_.28one_spinless_particle_in_1d.29), he had some general concept of the pieces, then he **formulated** that vague idea into an equation. All I want to know is, how do you do that. It seems like a good way to learn is to try to take something that is relevant to my life, and make it into an equation. Then I will _see_ how the process works. Then when I look at equations from other authors, I will have a more intuitive sense of what they are thinking.

Comment: @JackM So, what I gain is an understanding of how the process works. The process of taking a somewhat vague notion, and formulating it into a mathematical expression.

Comment: "Input = thoughts, output = equation. How?" There is no way. This does not happen. You cannot take vague thoughts and convert them into mathematical symbols, because that is not what mathematical symbols are for.